# Getting Null from value using IOptionSnapshot<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, abp

I'm trying to implement Azure App Configuration to my Application that uses the ASP.NET Boilerplate Framework. I'm following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app?tabs=core3x) but when I try to access my settings everything comes null. When the Startup.cs get executed I can see the values in the constructor but  when I try to get them else where I get the null.

Program.cs:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((config) =>
                {
                    // Retrieve the connection string
                    IConfiguration settings = config.Build();
                    string connectionString = settings.GetConnectionString("AppConfig");
                    // Load configuration from Azure App Configuration
                    config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                    {
                        options.Connect(connectionString)
                               // Load all keys that start with `TestApp:` and have no label
                               .Select("TestApp:*", LabelFilter.Null)
                               // Configure to reload configuration if the registered sentinel key is modified
                               .ConfigureRefresh(refreshOptions => refreshOptions.Register("TestApp:Settings:Sentinel", refreshAll: true));

                    }).Build();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
  public class Startup
    {
        private const string _defaultCorsPolicyName = "localhost";

        private const string _apiVersion = "v1";

        public IConfigurationRoot _appConfiguration;

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _appConfiguration = env.GetAppConfiguration();
            Configuration = configuration; //Azure App Configuration
        }

        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //MVC
            services.AddControllersWithViews(
                options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(new AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
                }
            ).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new AbpMvcContractResolver(IocManager.Instance)
                {
                    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
                };
            });



            IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
            AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);

            services.AddSignalR();

            // Configure CORS for angular2 UI
            services.AddCors(
                options => options.AddPolicy(
                    _defaultCorsPolicyName,
                    builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins(
                            // App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address separated by comma.
                            _appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                                .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                                .ToArray()
                        )
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                )
            );

           
                options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

                // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });
            });


            services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
            // Bind configuration "TestApp:Settings" section to the Settings object
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<Settings>(Configuration.GetSection("TestApp:Settings"));

            // Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
            return services.AddAbp<RptWebHostModule>(
                // Configure Log4Net logging
                options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                    f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
                )
            );
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseAbp(options => { options.UseAbpRequestLocalization = false; }); // Initializes ABP framework.

            app.UseCors(_defaultCorsPolicyName); // Enable CORS!

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAbpRequestLocalization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<AbpCommonHub>("/signalr");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("defaultWithArea", "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

                options.IndexStream = () => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                options.DisplayRequestDuration(); // Controls the display of the request duration (in milliseconds) for "Try it out" requests.  
            }); 
            // Use Azure App Configuration middleware for dynamic configuration refresh.
            app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();
        }
    }
```

Custom Controller where I get the null values:

```
   [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AzureAppConfigTest : AbpControllerBase
    {
        public Settings _settings { get; }

        public AzureAppConfigTest(IOptionsSnapshot<Settings> options
)
        {
            _settings = options.Value; 
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string Test()
        {
            return _settings.Message; // The Problem is here
        }

    }
```

I need to get the values else where in the Application, I tried changing IOptionsSnapshot for IOptions but I can't make it work, Iv'e been stuck with this about two week but since I'm new in the Microsoft world I can't see clearly where the problem is, Thanks in Advance

Update:

I am able to use the configuration at the Presentation Layer, but If I try to use it on the Application layer I don't get the values.

Comment: First you have to check that you are connecting to Azure to read the configuration and then that it is filtering where you configure the sections, send me an email shin321654987@gmail.com maybe I can help you.

Comment: Hi, I can say that I'm connected to Azure because I can see the configuration values in the Startup.cs ConfigureServices method